# Get ID of newly-created worksheet?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using the [PHPExcel library](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to **open an existing Excel spreadsheet** then **create a new worksheet in it**.

The code I'm using (excluding all of the initialisation/save etc. as that all works correctly) is as follows:

```
#======================================================#
#  OPEN EXISTING EXCEL SPREADSHEET                     #
#======================================================#

    if (!file_exists( CURRENT_FILE )) {
        exit("Please run " . CURRENT_FILE . " first." . EOL);
    }

    echo date('H:i:s') , " Load from Excel2007 file" , EOL;
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load( CURRENT_FILE );

#======================================================#



#======================================================#
#  SET UP WORKSHEETS                                   #
#======================================================#

    echo date('H:i:s') , " Create new worksheet for month" , EOL;
    $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle( date("d M", strtotime( $weeks[1] ) ) . ' - ' . date("d M", strtotime( $weeks[4] ) ) );

#======================================================#
```

What I'm **trying** to do is:

- Open existing Excel file (which may have 1 or more worksheets in already)
- Create a new worksheet
- Set the new worksheet's title
- Add content to the new worksheet

However, what **seems to be happening** is this:

- Opens existing Excel file
- Creates a new worksheet
- Set's the FIRST worksheet's title to the date I've set up
- Adds content to the FIRST worksheet

[image: PHP Excel Worksheets]

So, what I think I need to do is this:

- Open existing Excel file
- Add new worksheet
- Get ID of newly-added worksheet (a command like `mysql_insert_id()`)
- Set active worksheet to that ID
- Set title of active worksheet
- Add content to active worksheet

However, I can't seem to find such a command in the PHPExcel documentation. Does one exist? If not, is there any viable workaround to this? I don't want to overwrite the existing worksheets in this document.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: WHich version of PHPExcel? Are you using the latest 1.7.8 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of the fact that the createSheet() method actually returns your new worksheet.

```
$newMonthSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
$newMonthSheet->setTitle( date("d M", strtotime( $weeks[1] ) ) . ' - ' . date("d M", strtotime( $weeks[4] ) ) );
```

Comment: Superb. Then, for adding content, do I simply use `$newMonthSheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', ''value' );`?

Comment: Ah - removing the `getActiveSheet` command and that works fine. Just one more question if you're around Mark - how do I then set this latest sheet to be the `activeIndex`, i.e. the worksheet that Excel displays when you first open the file?

Comment: $newMonthSheet is a sheet object, not a workbook object, so you don't calll getActiveSheet() against the sheet... to set the active sheet, there's $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($n) where $n is the index of the sheet you wish to set as the active sheet, or($objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName($name) where $name is the name/title you've given the worksheet